# Add button with function call for generatet table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I´m filling a table with jquery from a JSON data source

```
var data = dataJSONMOV, 
           fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            tr, td, i, il, key;

for(i=0, il=data.length;i<il;i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for(key in data[i]) {
         td = document.createElement('td');
         td.appendChild( document.createTextNode( data[i][key] ) );
         tr.appendChild( td );
    }
    //Button generation code should go here (see below)
    fragment.appendChild( tr );
}
$('#mytable tbody').append( fragment.cloneNode(true) );
```

I want to add a button in the end of each row which calls a function **displayInformation(string ID)** with a parameter from the first coloumn of that row.

How can I accomplish that?

I tried it with this code but it doesn`t show me any buttons

```
 //Button generation code
 var btn = document.createElement('input');
 btn.type = "button";
 btn.className = "btn";
 btn.value = data[i][0];
 btn.onclick = (getTestAlert(data[i][0]));
 tr.appendChild(btn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right direction on how add the button. You can add it and them add an event listener to the table:

```
$('#mytable').on("click", "input", function() {
});

// Or 

$('#mytable').on("click", "input", getTestAlert);
```

So, to know what *id* it belongs, add a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes):

```
var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.dataset.id = data.id;
```

And how to retrieve it:

```
$('#mytable').on("click", "button", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id"); // For jQuery
        id = this.dataset.id; // For vanilla
});
```

Your loop would probably end like this:

```
for(i=0, il=data.length;i<il;i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for(key in data[i]) {
         td = document.createElement('td');
         td.appendChild( document.createTextNode( data[i][key] ) );
         tr.appendChild( td );
    }

    // Add button in last column
    var btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.type = "button";
    btn.className = "btn";
    btn.value = data[i][0];
    btn.onclick = (getTestAlert(data[i][0]));
    tr.appendChild(btn);

    fragment.appendChild( tr );
}
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/udajsqwk/)

Besides, I don't know if its some kind of a requirement, but if you're using jQuery, you should use it for your entire code, like the elements creating as well. Creating elements may be odd in some browsers and jQuery takes care of it. If you're interested, your code should became something like:

```
var data = dataJSONMOV, 
           fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
           key, html = "";

for(var i=0, il=data.length;i<il;i++) {
    html+= "<tr>";
    for(key in data[i]) {
         html+= "<td>" + data[i][key] + "</td>";
    }

    html+= "<td><input type='button' class='btn' value='Click me' data-id='" + data[i].id + "' /></td></tr>";
}

$("#mytable").append(html);
```

Pretty short, huh ?

Comment: Thanks so much for explanation an the fiddle... it`s working great

Answer (score 1):

Because you're populating the table dynamically, you need to add a click listener based on some parent defined in the html. Assuming this is the case for '#myTable tbody' and that the parameter from the first column of that row that you need for displayInformation() is accessible via .text(), you could use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function() {
    displayInformation($('td:first-child', $(this).parents('tr')).text());
  });
});
```

to create the click listener for the row's button.